# Is it possible to add New Row at the certain position in the jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have requirement of adding a new row for the button onclick.

Example

1. In the first row at the last cell. I have an ADD MORE button. If I click that button new row should be added below that first row.

Is it possible in jqGrid ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. The method addRowData has the needed parameters:

> addRowData(string rowid, mixed data, [string position], [string
>   srcrowid])
>
> Inserts a new row with id = rowid containing the data in data (an
>   object) at the position specified (first in the table, last in the
>   table or before or after the row specified in srcrowid). The syntax of
>   the data object is: {name1:value1,name2: value2…} where name is the
>   name of the column as described in the colModel and the value is the
>   value.

More on the method you can read in the [Gurrido jqGrid documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#method-list)